# Flutter: Error output from Xcode build (it builds the application for the simulator iPhone 14, but gives error on physical device (iPhone 11 Pro)

Tags: flutter

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Ulukbek in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: XANSRY3P9C
Xcode build done.                                           10.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/qx/b_pmk6dd4zd63cym4xls2g580000gn/T/flutter_tools.DRa5r8/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirYk8c7F/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKPhotoGallery' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: Signing for "DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
/Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: error: Signing for "DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GTMAppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'SwiftyGif' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'SDWebImage' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'DKImagePickerController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.0.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/qx/b_pmk6dd4zd63cym4xls2g580000gn/T/flutter_tools.DRa5r8/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirYk8c7F/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): Signing for "DKImagePickerController-DKImagePickerController" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj

Error (Xcode): Signing for "DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor.
/Users/ulikygyz/Flutter/ali_boss/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj


Error launching application on iPhone 11 pro(Physical device).
Exited
```

After updating to iOS 16, my app doesn't work on my physical device. but it works on simulator. When I run on physical device, it gives me error above. I tried to `flutter clean` and it didn't work.

`flutter doctor -v` shows no issues found!

I am using m1 Mac.

Comment: Since iOS 16 you need to turn on your developer mode on your iphone.

Comment: I have turned on my developer mode

Comment: "Signing for "DKPhotoGallery-DKPhotoGallery" requires a development team. Select a development team in the Signing & Capabilities editor." <-- follow the tip